# Azure SQL Server configuration SQL Server Connectivity Level locked/grayed out

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-sql-database

We have an Azure VM where SQL Server 2017 is installed. When the VM was set up, the level "local" was selected. Now we determined it should be private and not "local". We clicked the Edit pencil icon on the portal but the drop down box with supposedly 3 possible option values (`public, private, local`) is grayed out.

What can be done to open the drop down box and change the SQL Server connectivity level? SQL Server is configured with tcp/ip/named pipes/shared memory enabled and the SQL Server service was restarted but that made no difference.

Thanks

Comment: We have the same problem wanting to temporarily go from Private to Public

Answer (score 0):

It seems your browser issue. I test on Edge, I could modify it.

[image]

I suggest you could change a browser or change a PC and test again.

Comment: Same issue with Edge

Comment: We tried both IE and Chrome.  I will see if we can find a laptop with Edge.

Comment: We ended up deleting the VM and creating a new one setting it to private.  Surprisingly, it went back to local (??)  This is surreal.

Comment: We deleted the Azure VM again and finally got it set to private.  It is grayed out once it is set to private.  This means is what Bob is experiencing.

Comment: Sorry for the later answer, could you show some screenshot about this?